# Php Header location error

Tags: php

I have a php header location problem what i am doing is getting some data from my database and then making a if else check and depending on that i am redirecting the user to the next page ,here goes my code

```
            if($claim_status == 'Pending Verification')
        {
            $page = "pending-verification.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        }
        elseif($claim_status == 'Pending PO Clearance')
        {
            $page = "po-clearance.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        }
        elseif($claim_status == 'Payment Approved')
        {
            $page = "payment-approved.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        }
        elseif($claim_status == 'Payment Receipt')
        {
            $page = "confirm-claim.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        }
        elseif($claim_status == 'Billing')
        {
            $page = "billing.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        }
        elseif($claim_status == 'Billed')
        {
            $page = "billed.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        }
        header("Location:$page");
```

`$claim_status` is a variable i am getting from my database.

The error i am getting is ( this page has a redirect loop) how can i take care of this Please help me

Thank You

Comment: Try replacing the last header statement with print `header("Location:$page");` -> `print("Location:$page");` and see what gets printed.

Comment: Also, do you have any rewrite rules acting?

Comment: @SalmanA  cool dude i was not sure it can be done thumbs up

Comment: you should not use so many else if, use an array instead

Comment: ...or a case statement, or a functional mapping.

Comment: @kevin var_dump() will also help.
As yes123 pointed out, you shouldn't use that much else if,case-switch structure is easier to read.
And make sure you give default fallback option, should something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you emit a `Location` header no matter what (the `header` statement isn't inside an `if` … at least not in the code you've shared), so it will always redirect (and always with a malformed Location header, even when `$page` is defined, it fails to be an absolute URI).

Only emit the `Location` when you actually want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question, but you should avoid so many else if.
Your code should look like this:

```
$allowedStatus = array ( 
    'Pending Verification' => 'pending-verification',
    'Pending PO Clearance' => 'po-clearance'
    //> Etc
);
```

At this point is easy to build your `$page` var

```
$page = $allowedStatus[$claim_status] . '.php?verifyid=' . $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case instead of if-elsif statements.
Also, make sure there's no other php output before header();

```
switch($claim_status) {

    case 'Pending Verification':
        $page = "pending-verification.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        break;

    case 'Pending PO Clearance';
        $page = "po-clearance.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        break;

    case 'Payment Approved';
        $page = "payment-approved.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        break;

    case 'Payment Receipt';
        $page = "confirm-claim.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        break;

    case 'Billing';
        $page = "billing.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        break;  

    case 'Billed';
        $page = "billed.php?verifyid=".$id."";
        break;


    default:
        $page = ''; //Set a default rediraction page in case $claim_status is invalid.
        break;

}

header("Location:$page");
```

Comment: this is just bad as the else if, read my answer to get a better code

Comment: I saw it after i posted the answer. Much better version. Only thing you need to do, is to check if the array key exists so that the $page will be always valid.

if (array_key_exists($claim_status, $allowedStatus)) {
    $page = $allowedStatus[$claim_status] . '.php?verifyid=' . $id;
} else { $page = "error_handling.php"; }

Answer (score 0):

You may use javascript to stop redirection loop

```
<?php
   $redirect_page = 'page.php';
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location=$redirect_page</script>";
?>
```